# Combine two Pandas dataframes, resample on one time column by averaging

Tags: python, pandas

My question is somewhat similar to this one with a few key differences:

[Combine two Pandas dataframes, resample on one time column, interpolate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517125/combine-two-pandas-dataframes-resample-on-one-time-column-interpolate)

I have two data sets acquired simultaneously by different acquisition systems with different sampling rates - one acquires data every one second (df2) and the second acquires data every 11 minutes (df1). I would like to create a single dataframe containing both data sets where the time index of the combined dataframe will be that from the 11-minute sampling frequency dataframe (df1). The data within this dataframe will be the original data from df1 with the data from the 1-second dataframe (df2) averaged over the relevant 11 minute period and appended to df1.

Here is some example data:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

todays_date = datetime.now().date()
index1 = pd.date_range(todays_date-timedelta(10), periods=10, freq='11min')
index2 = pd.date_range(todays_date-timedelta(10), periods=6000, freq='S')
columns1 = [15, 17, 19, 21, 24, 27, 30, 34, 38, 43, 48, 54, 60, 67, 75, 84, 
94, 105, 118, 132, 148, 166, 186, 208, 233, 261, 292, 327, 366, 410, 459, 
514, 576, 645, 722, 809, 906]
columns2 = [103.73, 111.469, 119.786, 128.723, 138.327, 148.647, 159.737, 
171.655, 184.462, 198.224, 213.013, 228.905, 245.984, 264.336, 284.057, 
305.25, 328.024, 352.497, 378.797, 407.058, 437.427, 470.063, 505.133,     
542.82, 583.319, 626.839, 673.606, 723.862, 777.868, 835.903, 898.268, 
965.286, 1037.304, 1114.695, 1197.86, 1287.23, 1383.267, 1486.47, 1597.372, 
1716.548, 1844.616, 1982.239, 2130.13, 2289.054, 2459.835, 2643.358, 
2840.573, 3052.502, 3280.243, 3524.975, 3787.966, 4070.578, 4374.274, 
4700.629, 5051.333, 5428.202, 5833.189, 6268.39, 6736.061, 7238.624, 
7778.682, 8359.033, 8982.682, 9652.861, 10373.039, 11146.949, 11978.599, 
12872.296, 13832.67, 14864.696, 15973.718, 17165.483, 18446.161, 19822.39, 
21301.296, 22890.539, 24598.352, 26433.582]
data1 = np.random.rand(10, 37)*1000
data2 = np.random.rand(6000, 78)*1000
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, index=index1, columns=columns1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, index=index2, columns=columns2)
```

What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) + [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df2 = pd.concat([df1, df2.resample('11T').mean()], axis=1)
```

Alternative is use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) + [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df2 = pd.concat([df1, df2.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='11T')).mean()], axis=1)
```

For testing was created smaller `DataFrames` and freq in `df2` was changed to `1.1Min`:

```
np.random.seed(123)
todays_date = datetime.now().date()
index1 = pd.date_range(todays_date-timedelta(10), periods=2, freq='11min')
index2 = pd.date_range(todays_date-timedelta(10), periods=20, freq='1.1Min')
columns1 = [15, 17]
columns2 = [103.73, 111.469, 119.78]
data1 = np.random.randint(10, size=(2, 2))
data2 = np.random.randint(3, size=(20, 3))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, index=index1, columns=columns1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, index=index2, columns=columns2)
```

```
print (df1)
                     15  17
2017-04-29 00:00:00   2   2
2017-04-29 00:11:00   6   1

print (df2)
                     103.730  111.469  119.780
2017-04-29 00:00:00        2        1        2
2017-04-29 00:01:06        1        0        1
2017-04-29 00:02:12        2        1        0
2017-04-29 00:03:18        2        0        1
2017-04-29 00:04:24        2        1        0
2017-04-29 00:05:30        0        0        0
2017-04-29 00:06:36        1        2        0
2017-04-29 00:07:42        2        0        0
2017-04-29 00:08:48        1        0        1
2017-04-29 00:09:54        0        0        0
2017-04-29 00:11:00        2        1        1
2017-04-29 00:12:06        2        2        2
2017-04-29 00:13:12        1        0        0
2017-04-29 00:14:18        2        1        0
2017-04-29 00:15:24        2        2        2
2017-04-29 00:16:30        2        1        2
2017-04-29 00:17:36        0        1        0
2017-04-29 00:18:42        2        0        2
2017-04-29 00:19:48        1        2        0
2017-04-29 00:20:54        2        2        0
```

---

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2.resample('11T').mean()], axis=1)
print (df3)
                     15.000   17.000   103.730  111.469  119.780
2017-04-29 00:00:00        2        2      1.3      0.5      0.5
2017-04-29 00:11:00        6        1      1.6      1.2      0.9

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='11T')).mean()], axis=1)
print (df3)
                     15.000   17.000   103.730  111.469  119.780
2017-04-29 00:00:00        2        2      1.3      0.5      0.5
2017-04-29 00:11:00        6        1      1.6      1.2      0.9
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Out of interest is it possible to use the same approach when the time steps in df1 are irregular (by first reading the timestamps perhaps?)

Comment: I think yes, only get `NaN`s in rows where no data.

Comment: OK that sounds sensible.