# pandas: How to merge multiple dataframes with same column names on one column, with duplicate values?

Tags: python, pandas

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517125/combine-two-pandas-dataframes-resample-on-one-time-column-interpolate),

> I have two data sets acquired simultaneously by different acquisition systems with different sampling rates. One is very regular, and the other is not. I would like to create a single dataframe containing both data sets, using the regularly spaced timestamps (in seconds) as the reference for both. The irregularly sampled data should be interpolated on the regularly spaced timestamps.

I have the exact same situation, but my `t` column may have duplicates.
I would like to remain for each rows whose t is duplicated, with the one whose data column is maximal.

Following the original example:

```
df1:
    t   y1
0  0.0  0.0
1  0.5  0.5
2  1.0  1.0
3  1.0  3.0
4  1.5  1.5
5  2.0  2.0

df2:
    t    y2
0  0.00  0.00
1  0.34  1.02
2  1.01  3.03
3  1.40  4.20
4  1.60  4.80
5  1.70  5.10
6  2.01  6.03


df_combined:
     t   y1   y2
0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.5  0.5  1.5
2  1.0  3.0  3.0
3  1.5  1.5  4.5
4  2.0  2.0  6.0
```

notice t=1.0, y1=3.0 now

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you mind to produce an [mcve](/help/mcve)? In your case there are not duplicates in `t` and to obtain your expected `df` you just need to follow the same question you are refering to.

Comment: notice t=2 and t=3 in df1

Answer (score 1):

There are three tasks:

1. drop duplicates on `df1`
2. interpolate `df2`,
3. merge the two

So here's a solution

```
(df2.set_index('t')
     .reindex(new_idx)
     .interpolate('index')
     .reset_index()
     .merge(df1.sort_values('y1', ascending=False)
               .drop_duplicates('t'),    
            on='t', how='right')
)
```

Output:

```
     t   y2   y1
0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.5  1.5  0.5
2  1.0  3.0  3.0
3  1.5  4.5  1.5
4  2.0  6.0  2.0
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are dealing with "TIMESTAMPS" then you have yo use datetime package which is one of the important one that individual not focused of and one of the important one for time series forecasting as well